# What version of .NET (or MFC?) will give the least installation hassle for my users?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I've created a very simple prototype application in Visual Basic 2010 Express. The problem is that it uses the 4.0 .NET runtime, so *every* test user has had to install new runtime libraries. This won't do for wide distribution where ever hurdle means fewer installs.

What version of .NET should I target for minimum friction? Or could I even use old-fashioned MFC, if I re-write in C++?

And will the latest version Visual Studio allow me to target any runtime version?

(I'm not using anything fancy in .NET -- it's actually based on a VB6 program. The application gets an image from TWAIN and sends the it to a server.)

Comment: I think you're making a mistake to generalize and say "every hurdle means fewer installs". The relationship may not be linear. Also, you can include the .NET Framework redistributable files as part of your installer, so there is no separate installation.

Comment: I think the least friction avoids .NET but as @John states, if you can add the heft, you can built it into your installer. .NET 2 is probably the least friction and most likely installed already on up to date machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio will allow you to target any framework version, located in the project properties. If you're really concerned about catering to a wider audience, and since you mentioned an option for rewriting it in C++, I would say go with that option.
Even though, it's safe to assume that anything above .NET 2.0 will be present in almost all machines, so if you had to pick a target framework, I'd go with that. Simply rebuild your solution once you change the target framework.

Comment: A C++ application will still require you to install the appropriate version of the CRT. You can't rely on it being there already.

Comment: In that case, targeting .NET 2.0 is the safest bet.

Comment: @CodyGray Not necessarily. C++ projects can opt to static link its runtime, so it doesn't depends at all in what's installed in the system.